# Why does lxml spit out an error at times (but not usual) in Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, lxml, elementtree

I frequently use `lxml` module in Python to scrape data from some web sites, and I'm comfortable with the module generally. However, when I try to scrape, at times I encounter `lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: AttValue: " or ' expected` error on `etree.fromstring()` call, but don't usually. I can't clarify how often I see that error, but I think one out of thousands or even tens of thousands times, I encounter the error. When I run the exactly same script immediately after the error occurred and the script stopped, I don't see the error and the script runs well as expected. Why does it spit out an ocasional error? Is there any way to deal with the issue? I have the similar problem when I instantiate urllib2.urlopen() function, but since I haven't seen the error from `urllib2` recently, I can't write the exact error message coming from it right now.

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it is *invalid* XML? Capture the data resulting in the error and validate it with a [XML/XHTML validator](http://validator.w3.org). (It is very unlikely that the error would non-deterministically occur for identical data - maybe the server returned something else?)

Answer (score 2):

Websites are written in (often invalid) HTML, not XML. You shouldn't be treating HTML as XML.

Use [lxml's HTML parser](http://lxml.de/parsing.html#parsing-html) and your problems should go away:

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

parser = etree.HTMLParser()
tree = etree.parse(urllib2.urlopen(url), parser)
```

If you find that lxml still chokes when trying to read the invalid HTML, you will have to find a more lenient parser. `html5lib` with BeautifulSoup is the most lenient (and also the slowest) HTML parser for Python:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url), 'html5lib')
```

Comment: Maybe, I should have clarified more, but I usually don't see the error; I just encounter the error, say, one out of 1,000~10,000 times when I try to scrape exactly the same page, which is exactly the same XML whenever I try to scrape. Also, the page consists of strict XML file, not invalid HTML file you often see around the web. Finally, even if I see the error, next time I try to scrape the same page, which consists of the exact same XML file (no change on any contents in the file), the error doesn't happen no more...

Answer (score 1):

I also had the problem that lxml's `iterparse()` would occasionally throw an `AttValue: ' expected` in a very unpredictable pattern. I knew that the XML I'm sending in is valid and rerunning the same script would often make it work (or fail at an entirely different point).

In the end, I managed to create a test case that I could rerun and it would immediately either complete or raise an `AttValue` error in a seemingly random outcome. Here's what I did wrong:

My input to `iterparse()` was a file-like object I wrote myself (I'm processing an HTTP response stream from requests, but it has to be ungzipped first). When writing the `read()` method, I cheated and ignored the size argument. Instead, I would just unzip a chunk of compressed bytes of a fixed size and return whatever byte sequence this decompressed to—often much more than the 32k lxml requests!
I suspect that this caused buffer overflows somewhere inside lxml, which led to the above issues. As soon as I stopped returning more bytes than lxml requested, these random errors would go away.